# Does Swift have something like "ref" keyword that forces parameter to be passed by reference?

Tags: pass-by-reference, swift

In Swift, structs and value types are passed by value by default, just like in C#. But C# also has a very usable ref keyword, that forces the parameter to be passed by reference, so that the same instance could be changed inside the function and accessed from the caller's scope afterwards. Is there a way to achieve the same result in Swift?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use the `inout` qualifier for a function parameter.

```
func swapTwoInts(a: inout Int, b: inout Int) {
    let temporaryA = a
    a = b
    b = temporaryA
}

swapTwoInts(&someInt, &anotherInt)
```

See [Function Parameters and Return Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_206) in the docs.

Comment: Nice. 'var' is deprecated in Swift 3, but 'inout' works.

Comment: Updated syntax - I'm using Xcode 8.0 and the current Swift 3 only accepts the `inout` qualifier just before the type, e.g.: `func swapTwoInts(a: inout Int, b: inout Int)`

Comment: @tracicot It's not the same. `var` was for having a mutable object in the local method scope - `inout` is for mutating the object at its own scope, from the method. Be careful.

Comment: What if the method is written in Objective C?