# How to do pointers in swift like I used to do in c++

Tags: c++, swift, pointers

So apple has had very little documentation I can find for doing this.  The big feature I miss from c++ is being able to do something like this (Sorry for any syntax errors I am a little rusty in c++

```
Int* Chosenint;
Int option1 = 1
Int option2 = 2
Int option3 = 3

if (the sun is up)
    Chosenint = &option1
else
    Chosenint = &option2
```

However swift doesnt recognize the "*" or the "&" operator.  All I am trying to do is have a global variable that stores a pointer to a SKSpriteNode, and can change to a different one.  All swift seems to have is the large UnsafeMutablePointer thing.  So how would you do that c++ code in swift but with skspritenodes?

Comment: Why use pointers at all?  This seems, if you'll pardon, a little pointless.  Just copy the value and be done with it.  In fact, it looks like your `optionx` variables should probably be constants, not variables (or, even better, an `enum` declaration).  Consider, perhaps, that whatever it is you're trying to do, you may be trying to do it wrong. see : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID146  This advice applies equally to C++

Comment: That said, if you really need to modify a value type by reference, you can encapsulate in a method and use `inout` parameters http://stackoverflow.com/q/24004062/327083

Comment: Looking for https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID23 ?

Comment: @immibis  ...and that was going to be my final link.  Beat me to it. ;)  Really, though, it is generally awful practice to try to force the structure of code from one language onto another just *"because it's what you're used to"*  Other devs will hate you, you end up making bad code, and you fail to learn how to leverage the new language in the way that it was intended to be used.  In this case, I think writing this code *swiftly* is probaby the right answer, rather than trying to kludge a pointer-based solution where one is really not needed.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am definitely learning the new way to do things.  However I do know that pointers sometimes speed things up especially when something has to be done TOOONS of times a frame.

Comment: @J.Doe If you're having performance issues, the only sane thing you can do is to *profile* your code to see where the bottleneck is.  In the case of native-sized integers it is identical in CPU cost to copy an address or a value so your above logic, even without profiling, is objectively unfounded.  There is no way that coping an `int*` is faster than an `int` - they are the exact same size.

Comment: I just realized that the code in your question is completely different from the question in the text you have written - you've used a value type (`int`) in your example but you're asking about a reference type `SKSpriteNode` in the text - these are entirely different things.  Swift adopts a similar convention to almost all other modern languages where classes and methods are treated as pointers ("reference types") implicitly (address copy).  Strings and other primitives (integers, floating point values, booleans, etc) as well as `struct`s are treated as value types (copy on assignment).

Answer (score 2):

> All I am trying to do is have a global variable that stores a pointer
>   to a SKSpriteNode, and can change to a different one. All swift seems
>   to have is the large UnsafeMutablePointer thing. So how would you do
>   that c++ code in swift but with skspritenodes?

`SKSpriteNode` is a class, i.e. reference type, so you don't need to do anything. You get the behavior without asterisks and ampersands.

Comment: WOAH! Seriously, how do i know if a type is a reference class?

Comment: @J.Doe You read [the Swift guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html), in particular the sections "Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types" and "Classes Are Reference Types".